# Calculate Days between Current Date and User Input Date Troubles

Tags: c++

The main goal of the program is to be able to ask the user for a date, for example their birthday, then output the amount of days they have been alive.

So my Main issue that I am running into here is trying to figure out how to make it so the program knows how many days are in a month and year.

I am asking the user for the current day, month and year in number format (example 1 1 2000)

right now when you add the results from betweenYear, betweenDay, and betweenMonth it is only giving me about 40 days depending on the year that I put in which in reality it should be in the thousands. I know this is because when asking the user for this information, the program doesnt know that these are actual dates, rather they are just numbers. I have no idea how to take the user information and turn them into actual dates in the program instead of just plain integers

So my question is: How do I define the amount of days in a month and days in a year while still using the numbers the user had input.

I only put in the section of code that I thought was necessary. (I am still very new to this and I have been doing a lot of research but have been unsuccessful in finding examples that are simple enough for me to comprehend.)

```
int main()
{
     cout << "Please Enter the day you were born. (EX 1-31) ";
     cin >> day;

     cout << "Please Enter the month you were born. (EX 1-12) ";
     cin >> month;

     cout << "Please Enter the year you were born. (EX 1990)";
     cin >> year;

     time_t t = time(NULL);
     tm* timePtr = localtime(&t);

     betweenYear = (timePtr->tm_year + 1900) - year;
     betweenDay = timePtr->tm_mday - day;
     betweenMonth = timePtr->tm_mon - month;
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: @chbchb55 when adding up the results from betweenYear, BetweenDay and betweenMonth. it only comes up to like 35 days when it should be in the thousands if the user is entering dates in the early 90's

Comment: You need to expand the years into days as well as the months first, so just normally expand them like the years would be 365 * betweenYear and you'd have to add in an extra day for every leap year so something like `(365*betweenYear)+((betweenYear-(betweenYear%4))/4)` and something similar for months

Comment: @chbchb55 That is exactly what I was looking for. I had initially thought to multiply by 365 but I figured it would come out with some crazy number. But now knowing how the time_t function works thats perfect! Really appreciate it. And what I plan on doing for the month section is just running it through a while loop to determine the days in the month for the user input.

Comment: The correct way to show you've solved the problem would be to add an answer showing how you've solved the problem.  In due course (48 hours or so, I believe), you'd be able to come back and accept your own answer — unless you've gotten a better one by then, of course.  You don't get the 2-point bonus if you accept your own answer.  Just putting 'solved' in the subject is not the right way to process this.  (You could add your solution to the question, but a self-answer is more appropriate, not least because it can bring closure to the question — it is clear that there is an answer.)

Comment: You've all forggoten about intercalary years

Comment: @user3811082 Nope that's what this `(365*betweenYear)+((betweenYear-(betweenYear%4))/4)` fixes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry about that. I wasnt sure how to go about doing that. I will adjust my code uptop to prove that it has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to expand the years into days as well as the months first, so just normally expand them like the years would be `365 * betweenYear` and you'd have to add in an extra day for every leap year so something like `(365*betweenYear)+((betweenYear-(betweenYear%4))/4)` and for months try that idea of yours to loop through them and use something like `days += (month_number-(month_number <= 7 ? 1 : 0)) % 2 && month_number != 2 ? 30 : month_number == 2 ? year_number % 4 == 0 ? 29 : 28 : 31;`.

Here is that ternary in expanded form:

```
int tmp_month = month_number;
if (month_number <= 7) {
    tmp_month -= 1;
}
if (tmp_month % 2 && month_number != 2) {
    days += 30;
} else if (month_number == 2) {
    if (year_number % 4 == 0) {
        days += 29;
    } else {
        days += 28;
    }
} else {
    days += 31;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the standard library to handle time related issues.

```
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const long long SECONDS_PER_DAY = 3600L * 24L;

long long days_since(int year, int month, int day) {
    // Current time since epoch
    time_t now = time(nullptr);

    // Convert year, month and day to a tm object
    tm beg = *localtime(&now);
    beg.tm_year = year - 1900;
    beg.tm_mon = month - 1;
    beg.tm_mday = day;

    // difftime returns seconds
    time_t bd = mktime(&beg);
    return static_cast<long long>(difftime(now, bd))/SECONDS_PER_DAY;
}
```

Comment: I did in the final code. I left all my library and namespace stuff out of the code posted here to shorten it up.